# Full screen Bootstrap table

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-tables

I'm creating what's basically a todo app that has a calendar, it's specifically for seniors/vision impaired people and I need the calendar to be the full height of the browser.

I'm using a Bootstap 4.5 bordered table for the calendar but still can't get it to be the full height of the browser.

I've tried setting the .table class height to 100%. I've also tried using the Bootstrap sizing and flex utility classes of "h-auto" and "d-flex" as well.

```
<table class="table table-bordered h-auto">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>Bird</td>
      <td>@LBird</td>      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give the table element the css style:

```
table{
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: min-height on the table has no effect. https://codepen.io/GeoHurdle/pen/XWjmbjw

Comment: In my browser (Chrome) it fills the entire height of the page. see your browser support in https://caniuse.com/?search=fill-available

Comment: I don't care about I.E. or Edge but I do want to support Firefox. Also, I noticed that not all td elements are the same width.

Comment: If this is the only element you can configure it this way: min-height: 100vh; , or change it according to the other elements that are likely to be on the page

Comment: OK, I used min-height: 100vh but I also had to use overflow: hidden on the body, Thanks